# how to deal with Adsense API - Android

Tags: android, oauth, adsense

I want to make an App to read my earning on Adsense.
I made an app on Google and I generated a URL to login into the App.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?from_login=0&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense&redirect_uri=xxxxxxxx&access_type=offline&as=-415b671ff3966dc2&pli=1&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&authuser=0&hl=en
```

but when the user login into the App and click on "Allow" the output has no access token just has "code".
also I want to know if there is an example of using google OAuth api on android because I tried to use it but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

There's an AdSense Management API sample for Android in:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/android

It uses Google Play Services to get the list of accounts on the device and the Google Client Library for Java to make the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, before calling any Google's API you need to be OAuth authenticated first, and thus to have a valid token.

Check this out to know how:

http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html